# Regex replace in case beetwen determinated chars (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, laravel

i have a mysql database that store up 1m ads. This ads have field "Ad_Content" and have random examples (Ad_Content):

> 1 CASE: \r\n{text...text...text...}\r\n\r\n\r\n <- This row is good

> 2 CASE: {text...text...}\r\n \r\n\r\n <- Wrong, have 1 space beetwen string "\r\n\r\n"

> 3 CASE: \r\n \r\n{text...}\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n <- Wrong, have 2 spaces beetwen string "\r\n\r\n"

> 4 CASE: \r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n{text...text...}\r\n \r\n\r\n \r\n <- Wrong, have 3 spaces beetwen string "\r\n*"

I try to remove all spaces found in the string "\r\n group" with REGEX but i can't get its.

Expected examples:

> 1 CASE: \r\n{text...text...}\r\n\r\n <- This row is good

> 2 CASE: {text...text...}\r\n\r\n\r\n (good)

> 3 CASE: \r\n\r\n{text...}\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n (good)

> 4 CASE: \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n{text...text...}\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n (good)

My code is:

```
$adContent  = $getDataAd->Ad_Content;
// This REGEX its ok, replace all \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n... for 2 <br> but broken if detect a space :(
$pattern    = "/(?:\r?\n[ ]*)+/"; 
$adContent  = preg_replace($pattern, "<br><br>", $adContent);
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do a regex replacement on the following pattern:

```regex
\r\n\s+(?=\r\n)
```

Sample script, using your third example as input:

```php
$input = "\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n{text...text...}\r\n \r\n\r\n \r\n";
$output = preg_replace("/\r\n\s+(?=\r\n)/", "\r\n", $input);
```

The trick here is to use the lookahead `(?=\r\n)` to *assert*, but not consume, a required following CRLF.  This way, we allow for the possibility of that following CRLF to also have unwanted spaces in front of it.

Comment: Thanks Tim! if excecute this script working good, but if get the string from the database not work, not detect the spaces.

Comment: This sounds like a data dependent thing, rather than a major problem with my answer.  If you can provide data for where my answer fails, maybe I can update.

Comment: Don't worry Tim, you aswer it's correct thanks. I if change all \r and \n for "<br>", how to limit to get 2 <br> if the string is "{text...}<br><br><br>(or more <br>)", "<br><br><br>(or more <br>){text...}<br><br><br>(or more <br>)" for get "<br><br>{text...}<br><br>"?

Comment: Replacing CRLF with a single `<br>`, then the equivalent regex pattern to use here would be: `/<br>\s+(?=<br>)/`

Comment: Thanks Tim, but the Regex /<br>\s+(?=<br>)/ not working: https://paiza.io/projects/sLcZE5fW99p3gfrxaZGDsg

Comment: You should ask another question.  You didn't ask here about `<br>`, you asked about CRLF.